# npm init shows code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', after installing nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I was already using node version 8.12.0. Then I installed nvm to use latest version of node (13.6.0). I ran cmd nvm use 13.6.0 . Now node is using latest version. Later on when I when tried npm init  I see this error

```
npm init
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

To solve this I adding each version path to system variable path

Note : this is windows 10 x64
[image]

Comment: Which version of NVM you are using? a [bug](https://github.com/tj/n/pull/470) fixed recently related to your situation.

Comment: I am using v1.1.7

Comment: I navigated to each of version file, node_modules folder is empty

Comment: do I install something manually?

Comment: There are two NVM projects AFAIK. [6.1.3](https://github.com/tj/n/releases) is the latest in this one (the one I use doesn't support Windows).

Comment: I got the same error with `npm start` after installing morgan with npm. I had to run my project with `node "c:\Users\RobertoCarlos\Workspaces\Javascript\apps\index.js"`, so the full route to my entry point file. I know it isn't a big solution but it works meanwhile...

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue on my windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, then realized was running from different directory then I cd into that and ran again and it worked.
Hope it will work for you too.
basically it was where file were located when you run it.
[See how its worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5yy9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same kind of issue, was not able to install any modules using npm or npx.And what i did was, i uninstalled the **nodejs** then i deleted the node path. After i installed the nodejs again and now it's working as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Haa well, I have spent two days on this and have done everything I can to fix this issue even tried resetting the system but none of them reloved the issue.
And accidentally found out what was causing this issue, it is because of `&` in my parent folder name. File hierarchy `R&D>remix>blog`, When I was trying to run the blog server it was throwing module not found, require stack error.

```
 code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
```

requireStack: []

***Solution:*** I have changed the parent folder name to `RnD` and it fixed the issue. If the file name contains any special characters(even parent folders) try updating it. In my case, it is `&`

Answer (score 0):

i used nvm and by delete npm-cache folder  from this path C:\Users'...'\AppData\Local
this problems solved